# Quando o clear() deve ser usado?

Tags: demoiselle

Fiz uma aplicação usando o padrão do arquétipo JSF-JPA para telas de lista e edição, extendendo de `AbstractListPageBean` e `AbstractEditPageBean` respectivamente, usando as páginas do Bookmark como referência.

Vi que o botão "Novo" e o "Excluir" tem o `actionListener` apontando para o método `clear()`. Nas telas de edição a `AbstractEditPageBean` tem o mesmo método mas não é chamado.

O `clear()` deve ser chamado sempre ao sair da tela, para evitar acúmulo de objetos em memória?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é exatamente para evitar o acumulo de memória, mas também ajuda. Na verdade nos métodos Novo e Excluir é preciso limpar as informações de um Bean que pode estar sendo listado ou editado. No caso do "Excluir" é mais claro, pois o registro foi lido e quando é excluído as informações dele deverão ser limpas. No caso do botão Novo, pode ser que tenha sido lido outro registro, e para garantir que não tem nada e feito o "clean".

Comment: Obrigado Emerson, entendi o uso. Estou tendo problemas de memória num servidor de produção com apenas uma aplicação (JBoss AS 7.1 + aplicação jsf+jpa Demoiselle 2.4.2) e estou investigando as possíveis causas.

Comment: É importante fazer um "profile" da aplicação. Verificar as configurações da JVM e do Servidor (run.conf). Algumas configurações fazem bastante diferença. Numa grande maioria dos casos, tanto os servidores quanto a JVM  são executados com as configurações "de fábrica" e isso não é o ideal.  Tem esse blog que traz uma boa visão inicial: http://blog.caelum.com.br/comecando-com-parametros-e-configuracoes-da-jvm/